# Small bars above and below the page number

Tags: numbering, footer, bar

I do need to introduce small bars above/under page numbers, I have checked out there is a similar question about a small bar over the page number, however, in my case does not work for the lower one.
I have tried  the next code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=2cm,bottom=3cm,left=2cm,right=4cm,marginparwidth=2.8cm,marginparsep=1cm}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\makeatletter
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\clearpairofpagestyles

\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\LARGE\bfseries}

\renewcommand\pagemark{\fcolorbox{white}{white}{\usekomafont{pagenumber}\thepage}}
 

\DeclareNewLayer[
    oddpage,
    background,
    page,
    addheight=-1cm,
    addwidth=-2cm,
    mode=picture,
    contents=\putLR{\stackanchor{\rule{30\p@}{2\p@}}{\pagemark}}
]{pagenumber.odd}

\DeclareNewLayer[
    clone=pagenumber.odd,
    evenpage,
    hoffset=2cm,
    contents=\putLL{\makebox[0pt][c]{\pagemark}}
]{pagenumber.even}

\AddLayersToPageStyle{scrheadings}{pagenumber.odd,pagenumber.even}

\AddLayersToPageStyle{plain}{pagenumber.odd,pagenumber.even}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}

\Blindtext[10]

\clearpage

\thispagestyle{empty}

{\Huge A page with empty page style.\par}

\clearpage

\Blindtext

\newgeometry{top=8cm,bottom=5cm,right=6cm,left=5cm,marginparwidth=2cm,marginparsep=3mm}

\Blindtext[10]

\end{document}
```

This is just an example of what I am trying. In this code, I will get the bar only in the odd pages, that's fine.

Any idea about how to add the same bar but just below the page number? It also would be very helpful to control the distance between bars and number.

Answer (score 1):

The following uses a `tabular` environment and places the rules using `booktab`'s `\toprule` and `\bottomrule`.

I changed the positioning a bit (I hope this is ok). The code now uses `\clap` around `\mypagemark`, which in turn puts the `tabular` around `\pagemark`. The `\clap` is used so that page numbers are centred on that position, so that for larger page numbers, the position is seemingly the same. You could also use `\llap` to make larger numbers grow to the left, or `\rlap` to make larger numbers grow to the right.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=2cm,bottom=3cm,left=2cm,right=4cm,marginparwidth=2.8cm,marginparsep=1cm}
\makeatletter
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\clearpairofpagestyles

\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\LARGE\bfseries}
\newcommand*\mypagemark
  {\begin{tabular}{c}\toprule[1.5pt]\pagemark\\\bottomrule[1.5pt]\end{tabular}}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\DeclareNewLayer[
    oddpage,
    background,
    page,
    addheight=-1cm,
    hoffset=\dimexpr\paperwidth-2cm\relax,
    mode=picture,
    contents=\clap{\mypagemark}
]{pagenumber.odd}

\DeclareNewLayer[
    clone=pagenumber.odd,
    evenpage,
    hoffset=2cm,
    contents=\clap{\mypagemark}
]{pagenumber.even}

\AddLayersToPageStyle{scrheadings}{pagenumber.odd,pagenumber.even}

\AddLayersToPageStyle{plain}{pagenumber.odd,pagenumber.even}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}

\Blindtext[10]

\clearpage

\thispagestyle{empty}

{\Huge A page with empty page style.\par}

\clearpage

\Blindtext

\newgeometry{top=8cm,bottom=5cm,right=6cm,left=5cm,marginparwidth=2cm,marginparsep=3mm}

\Blindtext[10]

\end{document}
```

[image]